# Define macro that scans ahead for super- and/or subscript, "absorbs" them and moves their argument

Tags: macros, subscripts, superscripts

I have a lot of mathematical macros that already have a super- and/or subscript by definition, i.e. something like

```
\newcommand*{\mymathsym}{x^{\text{foo}}_{\text{bar}}}
```

In the text body, these symbols frequently need an extra sup-/subscript. This means, the author must remember to put the main symbol into an pair of {}-braces, otherwise a double sup-/subscript error occurs.

```
\begin{equation}
  {\mymathsym}^{\text{extra}}
\end{equation}
```

The extra superscript becomes a secondary superscript and it set slightly higher and smaller:
[image: extra superscript]
This has two drawbacks: a) In the special field of application, both superscripts stand on the same hierarchy level from a conceptional viewpoint. In other words, both superscripts should actually be printed as a list "foo, extra" and the opposed order "extra, foo" would be equally good. b) If the primary sup- and subscript are very unbalanced in length, the secondary superscript is set far apart, e.g.

```
\newcommand*{\mymathsymlong}{x^{\text{foo}}_{\text{very long foobar}}}
```

and

```
\begin{equation}
{\mymathsymlong}^{\text{extra}}
\end{equation}
```

yields
[image: far apart superscript]

As a workaround, I currently use the following definition that takes an optional argument and appends the argument to the internal superscript:

```
\newcommand*{\mymathsymext}[1][]{x^{\text{foo}\if!#1!\else, #1\fi}_{\text{very long foobar}}}
```

(N.b. I know that the condition `\if!#1!` is not the correct way to test for an empty argument, because it fails if the argument expands to a `!`. But I think you get the idea what the macro does.)

It is used as

```
\begin{equation}
\mymathsymext \qquad\text{vs.}\qquad \mymathsymext[\text{extra}]
\end{equation}
```

and yields
[image]
However, this has two major drawbacks: a) `\newcommand` only supports a single optional argument. Hence I need to decide at design time, if either an additional superscript or an additional subscript might eventually be needed. I cannot support both. b) The user has to remember an unusual syntax for placing additional sup-/subscripts.

**Question:**

How does one define a macro `\mymathsymsuper` that

- scans ahead, if it is followed by a supscript character `^`<tok> and/or subscript character `_`<tok> each followed by an additional token <tok>
- "absorbs them", and
- moves <tok> to end of its internal sup-/subscript separated by a comma?

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\mymathsym}{x^{\text{foo}}_{\text{bar}}}

\newcommand*{\mymathsymlong}{x^{\text{foo}}_{\text{very long foobar}}}

\newcommand*{\mymathsymext}[1][]{x^{\text{foo}\if!#1!\else, #1\fi}_{\text{very long foobar}}}

\begin{document}

Here, the author must know that \verb#\mymathsym# has already a super- and subscript and must remember to put the main symbol into a pair of \{\}-braces, otherwise a double sup-/subscript error occurs.
The extra superscript becomes a secondary superscript and it set slightly higher and smaller:
\begin{equation}
{\mymathsym}^{\text{extra}}
\end{equation}

If the primary sup- and subscript are very unbalanced in their length, the secondary subscript is set very far apart:
\begin{equation}
{\mymathsymlong}^{\text{extra}}
\end{equation}

This extended macro takes an optional argument and ``absorbs'' the extra superscript into the primary superscript:
\begin{equation}
\mymathsymext \qquad\text{vs.}\qquad \mymathsymext[\text{extra}]
\end{equation}
Still, the author must remember this ``unusual'' syntax and it only supports either an extra super- or subscript, bot not both.

\paragraph{Question:}
How does one define a macro \verb#\mymathsymsuper# that
\begin{itemize}
  \item scans ahead if it followed by a superscript character $\verb!^!\langle \mathit{token}_\text{sup}\rangle$ and/or subscript character $\verb!_!\langle \mathit{token}_\text{sub}\rangle$ each followed by an    additional token $\mathit{token}_\text{sup}$ and $\mathit{token}_\text{sub}$ resp.
  \item ``absorbs them'', and
  \item moves $\mathit{token}_\text{sup}$ and/or $\mathit{token}_\text{sub}$ to end of its internal sup-/subscript separated by a comma?
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of `\text` is the wrong command to use in this context, it does not do what you think it does. If your languages is English, use `\mathrm` instead, else use `\textup`. See the `xparse` package for something capable of picking up sub- and super script.

Comment: @daleif I am very sure, that `\text` is the right command. It temporarily leaves math mode and allows to enter text in normal mode. My super- and subscripts are "normal" text, i.e. telling labels, like "next", "first", "prev", "last", "origin" and so on. They are not math variables but static entities that must be treated as a single object, i.e. it is always "next" not "n ext" nor "ne xt" nor similiar.

Comment: Nope, try this: `\textit{test $\text{test}$ test}` all three is now in italic. Textual indicies like your extra should be upright, _always_. Good macros should not depend on which context you use this. Wrong usage of the `\text` command is by far one of the most common error I see in manuscripts.

Comment: The `\text` command switches to the surrounding text context, not upright. So in say a theorem, the context will be italic and `\text` gives the wrong output. Leave `\text` for textual comments in displayed math and use the proper macros for the rest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a breeze with `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mymathsym}{e{^_}}{%
  x^{\mathrm{foo}\IfValueT{#1}{,#1}}_{\mathrm{bar}\IfValueT{#2}{,#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\mymathsym \\
\mymathsym^{\mathrm{extrasup}} \\
\mymathsym_{\mathrm{extrasub}} \\
\mymathsym^{\mathrm{extrasup}}_{\mathrm{extrasub}} \\
\mymathsym_{\mathrm{extrasub}}^{\mathrm{extrasup}}   
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `e{^_}` the macro looks ahead for `^` or `_` (in either order) and assigns `#1` to the superscript, `#2` to the subscript. You can test for the presence with `\IfValueT` (or `\IfValueTF` if you want to do some action with an absent sub/superscript).