# Typeset saturation function

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, typography

For the thesis that I'm writing I'm dealing a lot with input saturation, for which I would like to define a saturation function. To do so, I would like to have a symbol that represents saturation, as well as a way to define its upper and lower bounds, see the picture below.
[image]

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477182/math-saturation-symbol) I managed to find a way to implement a decent saturation symbol, used in the picture above. Credits go to [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes). However, I would like to be able to add the upper and lower bounds in a command, like `\sat_{-5}^{10}`, or simply `\sat{-5}{10}`. Since I'm not at all familiar with Tikz, I have no idea how to properly add these bounds (the picture above was made in Paint). Also, the bounds should have a smaller font, since now they're too large. What would be entirely completely useful is if the saturation symbol could be lowered a bit as well such that it's vertically centered, and if it could reshape like the `\sum` command, see the picture below, where the left version was created using math mode and the right was made in an `align` environment.
[image]

Is there anyone out there skilled enough and kind enough to help me out here?

The saturation symbol is created in a .tex file `saturation.tex` with content

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-.7,-.6);
\coordinate (B) at (-.2,-.6);
\coordinate (C) at (+.2,+.6);
\coordinate (D) at (+.7,+.6);
\draw [black, line width=3pt] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

after which one creates the command

```
\newcommand\sat{\ThisStyle{\kern.5\LMpt\includegraphics[height=2\LMex]{saturation}\kern.5\LMpt}}
```

to be able to type `\sat`. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\sat{\ThisStyle{%
  \kern.5\LMpt\includegraphics[height=2\LMex]{saturation}\kern.5\LMpt}}
\begin{document}
\centering

\sat

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifsat@limits
\sbox\z@{$\sum$}
\sbox\@ne{$\displaystyle\sum$}
\tikzset{sat/.search also=/tikz}
\def\satset#1{\tikzset{sat/.cd,#1}}
\satset{
  height/.store in=\sat@ht,
  is limits/.is if=sat@limits,
  nodisplay/.code={
    \@tempdima=\dimexpr\dp\z@+\ht\z@
    \pgfkeysalso{height=\@tempdima}
  },
  display/.code={
    \@tempdimb=\dimexpr\dp\@ne+\ht\@ne
    \pgfkeysalso{height=\@tempdimb}
  },
  nolimits/.style={is limits=false},
  limits/.style={is limits=true},
}
\NewDocumentCommand {\satpic} { O{} m m m } {
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0.5\dp\z@-0.5\ht\z@, x=1ex, y=1ex, sat/.cd, nolimits, nodisplay, #1]
  \coordinate (A) at (-\sat@ht/2,-\sat@ht/2);
  \coordinate (B) at (-\sat@ht/7,-\sat@ht/2);
  \coordinate (C) at (\sat@ht/7,\sat@ht/2);
  \coordinate (D) at (\sat@ht/2,\sat@ht/2);
  \draw [black, line width=.6pt, #2] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D);
  \ifsat@limits
    \IfValueT {#3} {
      \node [below=1.3pt, inner sep=0pt] at (current bounding box.south) {$\scriptstyle #3$};
    }
    \IfValueT {#4} {
      \node [above=1.3pt, inner sep=0pt] at (current bounding box.north) {$\scriptstyle #4$};
    }
  \else
    \IfValueT {#3} {
      \node [anchor=west, inner sep=0pt, xshift=.3ex] at (B) {$\scriptstyle #3$};
    }
    \IfValueT {#4} {
      \node [anchor=east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-.3ex] at (C) {$\scriptstyle #4$};
    }
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand {\sat} { E{!@_^}{{}{}} } {
  \mathchoice
  {\satpic[display, limits, #1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
  {\satpic[nodisplay, nolimits, #1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
  {\satpic[nodisplay, nolimits, #1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
  {\satpic[nodisplay, nolimits, #1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
}

\begin{document}
Saturation A: $\sat_{-5}^{10}$ and $\sat!{limits}_{123}^{456}$

Saturation B:
\[
  \sat@{red}_{10}^{200} \sat@{line width=1pt}_{40000}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like how your solution is able to deal with putting the bounds on top and below the symbol, but it seems I cannot implement your solution in my .tex file. When I compile, the symbol simply does not show. Since I'm a half-noob with my self-defined packages, it might well be that something is conflicting, but I have no idea how to find out. Any ideas?

Comment: I recompile it in overleaf with no error. You can open another question and provide an example and also the information about the compiler and the error.

Answer (score 9):

Using a technique of egreg at [Define macro that scans ahead for super- and/or subscript, "absorbs" them and moves their argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503208/define-macro-that-scans-ahead-for-super-and-or-subscript-absorbs-them-and-mo), I let `xparse` help with redefining `^` and `_` to handle the kerning.

This MWE uses the `saturation.pdf` supplied by the OP's code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sat}{e{^_}}{%
  \mathop{\IfValueT{#1}{\phantom{\scriptscriptstyle#1}\mathchoice
   {\kern-5pt}{\kern-5pt}{\kern-3pt}{\kern-2pt}}%
   \rawsat\mathchoice
   {^{\IfValueT{#1}{\mathllap{\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern14mu}}}%
    _{\IfValueT{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-13mu#2}}}%
   {^{\IfValueT{#1}{\mathllap{\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern14mu\strut}}}%
    _{\IfValueT{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-13mu#2}}}%
   {^{\IfValueT{#1}{\mathllap{\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern11mu\mathstrut}}}%
    _{\IfValueT{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-9mu#2}}}%
   {^{\IfValueT{#1}{\mathllap{\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern9mu}}}%
    _{\IfValueT{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-6mu#2}}}%
}}
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\rawsat{\ThisStyle{\kern.5\LMpt
  \includegraphics[height=2\LMex]{saturation}\kern.5\LMpt}}

\begin{document}
$x=\sat_{-5}^{10} u(t)$

$\scriptstyle x=\sat_{-5}^{10} u(t)$

$\scriptscriptstyle x= \sat_{-5}^{10} u(t)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And just to prove I have resolved the kerning even as the superscript width changes, here is the same example with a wider superscript:

[image]

**ADDENDUM:**

Here is a version that does not require an external image file to be dragged around, but instead saves the `tikz` image of it at initialization.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,mathtools,stackengine,tikz,scalerel}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sat}{e{^_}}{%
  \mathop{\IfValueT{#1}{\phantom{\scriptscriptstyle#1}\mathchoice
   {\kern-5pt}{\kern-5pt}{\kern-3pt}{\kern-2pt}}%
   \rawsat\mathchoice
   {^{\IfValueT{#1}{\mathllap{\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern15mu}}}%
    _{\IfValueT{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-14mu#2}}}%
   {^{\IfValueT{#1}{\mathllap{\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern15mu\strut}}}%
    _{\IfValueT{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-14mu#2}}}%
   {^{\IfValueT{#1}{\mathllap{\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern12mu\mathstrut}}}%
    _{\IfValueT{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-10mu#2}}}%
   {^{\IfValueT{#1}{\mathllap{\scriptscriptstyle#1\mkern10mu}}}%
    _{\IfValueT{#2}{\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-7mu#2}}}%
}}
\newcommand\rawsat{\ThisStyle{\kern.5\LMpt
  \scaleto{\rawsatimg}{2\LMex}\kern.5\LMpt}}
\savestack\rawsatimg{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-.7,-.6);
\coordinate (B) at (-.2,-.6);
\coordinate (C) at (+.2,+.6);
\coordinate (D) at (+.7,+.6);
\draw [black, line width=3pt] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
$x=\sat_{-5}^{10} u(t)$

$\scriptstyle x=\sat_{-5}^{10} u(t)$

$\scriptscriptstyle x= \sat_{-5}^{10} u(t)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very well done! Although I'm actually not so much a fan of having to "drag around" the `saturation.pdf` file to new documents, is there an easy way to avoid this? And it seems the bounds' font size does not decrease when decreasing the overall font size, is that correct?

Comment: @StevenHorstink Please see **ADDENDUM** to my answer.

Comment: @StevenHorstink As to the font size, it is always done in `\scriptscriptstyle`.  For OT1 font encoding of the Computer Modern font, there is a lower limit ( I think around 5 pt) for the font size.  Try loading the `lmodern` package (reworks the Computer Modern Font as a T1 *scalable* font and calls it latin modern) and see if that resolves the font size issue.